# Reconstructing a classified image from a simple Convolution Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

I have a CNN trained on a classification task (Network is simple, 2 convolution + pooling layers and 2x fully connected layers). I would like to use this to reconstruct an image if I input a classification label.

Is this possible to achieve?

Is it possible to share weights between corresponding layers in the 2 networks?

Comment: If your question is answered please mark it

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to cGAN implementation and why not DeepDream from Google ;)
The answer is `yes it is possible`, however it's not straight forward